# Is it possible to set class to textbox using fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I want to add class to the textbox, how could I add that using fabric.js

canvas.set('class','textbox1');

Right now here i'm using canvas.set('class','textbox1'); for add any class.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary to use a class on a canvas element. Fabric.js has methods for their TextBox object with which you can style your component. The same goes for the Canvas object itself.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Textbox.html

Fabric doesn't appear to have a Class option and CSS has no effect on canvas objects anyway.

So, if you wanted to set the background color of your TextBox you would do the following:

```
var t1 = new fabric.Textbox('My Text', {
    width: 200,
    top: 5,
    left: 5,
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'rgb(200,200,200)'
});
```

Comment: that I know, but I want to put the class name, the reason is I want to customize the textbox, as Autocomplete textbox using Jquery and database, if you find any solution please help.

Comment: CSS has no affect on canvas elements so adding a class, even if it were possible, would do nothing

Comment: Thanks for revert, I have done with                                    
                         document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    alert(canvas.getActiveObject().text);
  };